# Load file into mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to load a tab delimited file into mysql database. My database is set up with columns: ID;A;B;C;D;E and my file is a dump of columns ID and D. How can I load this file into my db and replace just columns ID and D, which out changing the values of columns C and E. When I load it in now, columns C and E are changed to DEFAULT:NULL.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. If you are using something besides straight SQL, please make that clear in your question body (and add appropriate tag to your question too). I gave the answer for straight MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already answered a similar question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572615/php-save-multiple-rows-from-csv-to-mysql/10572652#10572652), but in your case, you'd want to load the csv into a temporary table, then use a simple update SQL statement to update the specific columbs from your temporary table to your production table.

Comment: Not that Ben Lees answer wouldn't work, but this would be faster with the LOAD IN FILE, and generally all done with SQL

Comment: I created a new table in the db, and uploaded my file to that table, then did a join with ID and updated D

Comment: Then that should have worked, depending on what you specified in the UPDATE statement using that JOIN.  What was that SQL statement?

Comment: It worked! Thanks. My sql join statement was: update products p join temp_att t on t.id = p.id set p.`pr_attributes`= t.`attri`

Comment: As long as it worked :)  Your reply didn't indicate that one way or the other :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update specific column using this command:

```
UPDATE the_table
SET D=<value-of-D>
WHERE ID=<value-of-ID>
```

Then run this command for each row in the tab-delimited file, replacing the D and ID values for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stored procedure or a PHP program to do the needful.

For MySQL, the SP would need to open the file using [load_file()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) and storing the value in a variable. Then the program needs to loop through by finding "\n" which stands for new line to get a whole line in a string.

Then the program needs to be find the first tab position using [locate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and by using [substring()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) get the first ID col. Then the program needs to find the 4th tab i.e. 3 more tabs by using locate() and its 3rd parameter. This will be the starting position of your D column. Then find the next tab character again using locate() and its 3rd parameter which will give you the end character of the D column. Using substring() get the content of the D column. Use a update command to update the row's D column using ID as the search key in the where clause.

Since the above will loop through all lines you will update all rows of data.