# How to batch load a CSV columns into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

I have numerous csv files that will form the basis of a mysql database. My problem is as follows:

The input CSV files are of the format:

TIME | VALUE PARAM 1 | VALUE PARAM 2 | VALUE PARAM 3 | ETC.
0.00001 | 10 | 20 | 30 | etc.

This is not the structure I want to use in the database. There I would like one big table for all of the data, structured something like:

TIME | PARAMETER | VALUE | Unit of Measure | Version

This means that I would like to insert the combination of TIME and VALUE PARAM 1 from the CSV into the table, then the combination of TIME and VALUE PARAM 2, and so on, and so on.

I haven't done anything like this before, but could a possible solution be to set up a BASH script that loops through the columns and on each iteration inserts the combination of time + value into my database?

I have a reasonable understanding of mysql, but very limited knowledge of bash scripting. But I couldn't find a way out with the mysql LOAD DATA INFILE command.

If you need more info to help me out, I'm happy to provide more info!

Regards,

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do this all day, every day, and as a rule, have the most success with the least headaches by  using LOAD DATA INFILE to a temporary table, then leveraging the power of mySQL to get it into the final table/format successfully.  Details at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606343/load-file-into-mysql/10606519#10606519).

To illustrate this further, we process log files for every video event of 80K highschools/colleges around the country (that's *every* pause/play/seek/stop/start for 100's of thousands of videos).

They're served from a number of different servers, depending on the type of videos (WMV, FLV, MP4, etc.), so there's some 200GB to handle every night, with each format having a different log layout.  The old way we did it with CSV/PHP took literally days to finish, but changing it to LOAD DATA INFILE into temporary tables, unifying them into a second, standardized temporary table, then using SQL to group and otherwise slice and dice cut the execution time to a few hours.

Comment: Thanks Greg,  I will look into that. I guess I would still need to loop through the columns, but now in the temp table. That should be possible with a procedure right?

Comment: Yes...the net effect of this is that you've got your raw data in a far more manageable format that you can inspect and manipulate with much more ease and accuracy.  Looping/saving/etc. will depend ultimately on what you want for your finished product.  Hope this helps and that you'll "Accept" my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easiest to preprocess your CSV with an `awk` script first, and then (as Greg P said) use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. If I understand your requirements correctly, this awk script should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -F| -f

NR==1 { 
    for(col = 2; col <= NF; col++) label[col] = $col
    printf("TIME | PARAM | VALUE | UNIT | VERSION\n")
    next 
}

{
    for(col = 2; col <= NF; col++) {
        printf("%s | %s | %s | [unit] | [version]\n", $1, label[col], $col)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.awk test.in
TIME | PARAM | VALUE | UNIT | VERSION
0.00001  |  VALUE PARAM 1  |  10  | [unit] | [version]
0.00001  |  VALUE PARAM 2  |  20  | [unit] | [version]
0.00001  |  VALUE PARAM 3  |  30  | [unit] | [version]
0.00001  |  ETC.   |  etc. | [unit] | [version]
```

Then

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'processed.csv' 
mysql> INTO TABLE 'table' 
mysql> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
mysql> IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

(Note: I haven't tested the MySQL)

Comment: Thanks Kevin! This should work as well. I guess (as Greg said) you have a bit more power of the raw data from a temp table. But both your approaches are what I was looking for.